# Reached end of file while parsing ERROR?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am getting an error BankInterest(line 93): reached end of file while      parsing, anyone know why i am getting this? Here is my code below so you can determine what the problem may be.

Thank you in advance.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io;

public class BankInterest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

/* TASK 1: Declare variables */

String accountType;
double principal;
double rate;
double balance;
int year;

 /* Check if the expected command line is provided */

  if (args.length < 1) {
 /* Display the Usage */
   System.out.println("Usage: java BankInterest interestRateFileName");
 /* Programs quits with an error code */
   System.exit(-1);
  }
  /* TASK 2: Read interest rates from a file */
 try {

   Scanner x = new Scanner(Paths.get("commbank.txt"));
   System.out.println(x.nextDouble());
  } catch (IOException e) {

  /* TASK 3: Take user input - Which Account */

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Which Account: ");
  System.out.println("1 - Savings");
  System.out.println("2 - Term Deposits");

  String line = keyboard.nextLine();

  if (line.equals("1")) {
   accountType = "Savings";
  } else if (line.equals("2")) {
   accountType = "Term Deposits";
  }

 /* TASK 4: Take user input - Principal and Period */

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Principal: ");
  principal = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Years: ");
  year = keyboard.nextInt();

  /* TASK 5: Calculate balance for the chosen account type */

  if (accountType == "Savings") {
   balance = principal * Math.pow((1 + rate / 100), year);
  } else if (accountType == "Term Deposits") {
   balance = (principal * rate * time) / 100;
  }

  /* TASK 6: Display results */

 if (accountType == "Savings") {
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("The Compound Interest is: " + balance);enter code here
 } else if (accountType == "Term Deposits") {
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("The Simple Interest is: " + balance);
 } else {
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Error! Account is not recognized.");
 }
}
```

Comment: At the end closed brace `}` is missing.

Comment: Use `equals()` for string comparison in java. Ex `if (accountType == "Savings")` should be `if (accountType.equals("Savings"))`.

Comment: why is task3 onwards running in a catch block?  Why do you open new Systen.in scanners?

Comment: In BankInterest.java change `import java.io;` to `import java.io.*;`. Insert another two (2) `}` in the end. Reformat your code (your IDE can do that, at least after you have corrected the syntax as just described). The error message means that the compiler thinks something is missing in the end of the file. While that is not always a correct guess, a good thing to try is usually to insert more `}` and see if it helps.

Comment: Next time see if you cannot produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please. Obviously, when the question is about a compilation error, as here, it should not be possible to compile your minimal example.

Comment: BTW, one of the inserted `}` should probably go after `} catch (IOException e) {`, and then with something in between to report the error to the user and/or exit the program. But you can decide that better than I.

Comment: I suggest using consistent formatting. This will help you see right away when you are missing any braces. Good programming editors and IDEs have a formatting option to help make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two more closing braces at the end of the file.

- One to close your main
- And the other to close off your class.

Also, you should use equals() when comparing `accountType` as Satya mentioned in the comment.